# Min Date and Max date

Tags: c#

I have a list of dates as below

```
 List<string> nameList = new List<string>();
 nameList.Add("20120618PM");
 nameList.Add("20120622PM");
 nameList.Add("20120622AM");
 nameList.Add("20120628PM");
 nameList.Add("20120702PM");
 nameList.Add("20120629AM");
 nameList.Add("20120629PM");
```

I want to find MAXDATE and MIN DATE from the list .Please let me know how can i proceed.

Regards,
Channa

Comment: You have a list of strings, your first problem is converting them to dates. They appear to be dates with a further distinction of morning or afternoon. If you can define how to parse the `strings` to `DateTimes` then its a trivial problem. I can see several logical possibilites.

Comment: Just use a better datatype for a date than string and it should be easy.

Comment: What is the format ? is it YYYYMMDD or Year with Time ?

Comment: @Channa there's a lot of activity on this question; but the question by @Default is intended to nudge in the direction of asking a good SO question.  At the moment, your question is basically - 'here's some data, give me some code' without any information about what you've done.  It's possible you don't *know* of any way to do this, but I'm guessing being a .Net developer you are aware of `DateTime` and therefore it's reasonable that you've tried to do something with that, or at least you've come across a reason why you couldn't.  You should include that information.

Comment: @Andras : Sure Thank you i will include . what i have tried .

Comment: @Habib.OSU : Yes it is YYYYMMDD

Comment: @Channa, I have post an answer for the format you specified in your comments

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the date format is yyyyMMdd then is is sortable as strings even with AM/PM

```
 nameList.Max()
```

If you have a year plus hours/minutes and AM/PM then you must parse to DateTime. I recommend parsing regardless, as suggested in other answers.

Comment: True. Added a note about that. (needs 24h, not am/pm). On a side note Non-sortable date formats should be banned ;)

Comment: In fact I think it is sortable since it is yyyyMMdd so AM comes before PM on any given date. So my original formulation actually holds.

Comment: Well - realistically our coder needs to be using `DateTime`s!

Comment: @AndrasZoltan I agree. The example should use DateTime. However if one already has a list of dates in a text-sortable format, then parsing to DateTime only fr sorting feels unnecessary. In fact, I'm not even sure this Dateformat can be parsed? What would the representation be in DateTime for "20120705PM" (afternoon of July 5:th). You'd need to manually split/parse as suggested in other answers and then sort the resulting DateTime objects. I say just sort the strings if that is all that's needed.

Comment: Yeah it's a good point.  I've just realised my -1 is unwarranted... because it's month day morn/avo.  So I've turned it into a +1.  God that string format is horrible though!

Answer (score 6):

What format is that? `"yyyyMMddtt"`?

There is AM PM with date. There is no time to accompany AM/PM. So I am assuming AM is 00:00:00 and PM is 12:00:00

First correct your format then use this

```
List<DateTime> temp = nameList.Select(x => 
DateTime.ParseExact(x, "yyyyMMddtt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)).ToList();
```

Then

```
temp.Min("yyyyMMddtt");

temp.Max("yyyyMMddtt");
```

Comment: I think perhaps `ParseExact`?  Also the ToString needs `tt` not `PM`

Comment: Also "PM" won't come out as "PM" but as "P"{number of month}.

Answer (score 2):

```
// 1. Convert your string list to datetimes  
IEnumerable<DateTime> dates = nameList.Select(m => DateTime.Parse(m, yourFormatProvider));

// 2. Get first and last date
DateTime maxDate = dates.Max();
DateTime minDate = dates.Min();
```

Comment: I don't think you can `Union` a `DateTime` with another `DateTime`.

Comment: @Rawling I am sorry you are right. I was to fast I have changed it. Thanks

Comment: why create a new `List`:  `new[] { dates.Max(), dates.Min() }` is better? or, better still - `var min = dates.Min(); var max = dates.Max();`  Also there's a question over the parsing of the strings - DateTime.Parse won't parse these strings.  `ParseExact` is better.

Answer (score 1):

If I had to guess, which it seems I do. I would do this

```
var dates = nameList.ConvertAll(s => {
        var dateString = s.SubString(6);
        var timeString = s.SubString(7, 2);

        var date = DateTime.Parse(dateString);

        if (timeString == "PM")
        {
           date = date.AddHours(12);
        }

        return date;
    });

var max = date.Max();
var min = date.Min();
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you have specified your format as `yyyyMMdd` in your comment, you need to trim `PM` and `AM` from the string

```
List<DateTime> dateList = 
  nameList.Select(x =>
  DateTime.ParseExact(
                      x.TrimEnd("PM".ToCharArray()).TrimEnd("AM".ToCharArray()), 
                     "yyyyMMdd", 
                      CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
                      ).ToList();

            var Minimum = dateList.Min();
            var Maximum = dateList.Max();
            Console.WriteLine(Minimum.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine(Maximum.ToString());
```

This will give you:

> 6/18/2012 12:00:00 AM 
> 7/2/2012 12:00:00 AM