# DateTime.ParseExact error in yyyyMMddtt

Tags: c#, datetime

I have a DateTime object

```
DateTime dtt = new DateTime(2012, 6, 18, 12, 0, 0)
```

I am converting it to string this way

```
string str = dtt.ToString("yyyyMMddtt");
```

I get `str` as "20120618PM"

Fine till here

But when I try to convert this back to DateTime using DateTime.ParseExact() i get an error
`String was not recognised a valid DateTime`

```
dtt = DateTime.ParseExact(str, "yyyyMMddtt", null);
```

I even tried providing culture but I still get an error

```
dtt = DateTime.ParseExact(str, "yyyyMMddtt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

What is wrong here which i am missing?

Comment: curiously similar to this question http://stackoverflow.com/q/11324718/659190

Comment: @Jodrell: I answered that questit on. but am confused about my answer.

Comment: So was I, I must admit. I don't think the conversion round trips, you are losing information on the `ToString`. Somthing like my answer to the other question would work.

Comment: @Jodrell: +1 to your answer of that question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the documentation for the [DateTime.ParseExact method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx) you will get a `FormatException` in the following case.

> The hour component and the AM/PM designator in s do not agree.

You don't have an hour component at all and there cannot be any agreement leading to the exception.

If you really want to stick with the format `yyyyMMddtt` you will have to perform your own parsing of the AM/PM part and based on that modify the time part of the `DateTime`. You can then parse the remainder of the date using `yyyyMMdd`.

Comment: What is the solution for this?

Comment: If you want to use an AM/PM designator you also have to include at least the hour part of the time for `DateTime.ParseExact` to be able to parse the date.

Answer (score 1):

This string `"20120618PM"` does not contain any `time`.

Are you sure it the same string you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

Have change the format yyyyMMdd hh:mm:ss hope its wrk

```
DateTime dtt = new DateTime(2012, 6, 18, 12, 0, 0);
string str = dtt.ToString("yyyyMMdd hh:mm:ss");
dtt = DateTime.ParseExact(str, "yyyyMMdd hh:mm:ss", null);
```

Answer (score 0):

As Martin and Asif has suggested, you must include hour into the string for ParseExact to determine AM/PM.

```
    DateTime dtt = new DateTime(2012, 6, 18, 12, 0, 0);
    string str = dtt.ToString("yyyyMMddhhtt");
    dtt = DateTime.ParseExact(str, "yyyyMMddhhtt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```